# How to pass data as parameter in react-table?

Tags: reactjs

How to pass data values as a parameter in React Table version 7.

I was trying to pass status and id in `butFunction` inside of react table so that i can create a function which create a button opposite of the status .

here is code what i had tried to do so.

[Demo Link of the same code](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-jackson-gyryo?file=/src/App.js:0-1875)

```
const data = [
  { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", status: "OPEN" , id: "1" },
  { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", status: "CLOSE"  , id: "2" },
  { firstName: "John", lastName: "Walker", status: "OPEN" , id: "3" }
];

const columns = [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Last Name",
        accessor: "lastName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status"
      }
];

const Table = ({ columns, data }) => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

    const butFunction = (level , id) => {
      console.log(level)
      console.log(id)
    if (level === "OPEN") {
      return <button > CLOSE </button>;
    } else {
      return <button > OPEN </button>;
    }
  };

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
              <td>{butFunction(data.status, data.id)}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access `row.values` to access the data for each row. Inside the `map` function, `row.values` will be an object that contains the data for the current row.

**Edit:**

As per your comment, `row.values` object doesn't contains `id` property of your data objects. To access the `id`, use `row.original.id`

```
<td>{ butFunction(row.values.status, row.original.id) }</td>
```

Comment: Hi @Yousaf by using this code i am getting undefined value for ```row.values.id``` how can i access this id

Comment: Hi @Yousaf Yes the edited answer solved my question Can you tell why its already being clicked without clicking in this ```https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wind-z9gd7?file=/src/App.js```

Comment: change `onClick={handleClick(id, level)}` to `onClick={() => handleClick(id, level)}`

Comment: can you tell why it would need to be changed?

Comment: because you need to pass a function to `onClick`, instead you were passing the return value of the `handleClick` function to `onClick`

Comment: oh great got it thankyou so much , but it does not goes inside of axios part